Corrupt Screen Display with Radeon Graphics
I assembled a new machine awhile back that includes an AMD Ryzen 5 5600G processor with Radeon Graphics.  All went well with the Ubuntu-22.04.4-desktop-amd64 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) image.  A couple of months ago, an update resulted in a corrupt screen image.  I can see everything is there, and remote SSH access is fine, but the screen display is distorted enough that I can't use the machine locally.  There is no flickering, but the display is mostly green with thin black lines.
I modified GRUB to add the boot menu with a 5 second timeout, which lets me boot into an older kernel.  The current version (6.5.0-21-generic) gives the corrupt screen display, while 6.2.0-39-generic boots with a normal screen display.
I just tried 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat) with a live USB, and it boots with the same corrupt screen display.
Please let me know if you can help me restore the screen display, or if I can provide any details that will help.  My experience with Ubuntu/Linux is not high, and I'm not terribly well-versed in this sort of thing, so details in your advice will be most welcome :)
Thank you in advance,
~Mike
